# The bug is fixed (in / at /with) version 1.0.45.2

Tags: prepositions, software

Which preposition I should use when adding a short note to a trouble ticket when I want to say: `"I have fixed the bug. App version 1.0.45.2 contains the fix"`?

My ideas are (not sure if any of them is correct):

- *Fixed in 1.0.45.2*
- *Fixed at 1.0.45.2*
- *Fixed with 1.0.45.2*

Comment: You forgot *fixed **by**.*

Comment: I would say, "Version 10.45.2 fixes the bug."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted syntax in the software community is to use *in* as the preposition.

> The bug is fixed in version 1.0.45.2.

Code gets added, changed, or removed as part of a new version release. The bug fix therefore lives *inside* of the version.